# Missionaries and Cannibals - LISP

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, breadth-first-search

The well-known Missionaries and Cannibals problem is as follows:

*Three missionaries and three cannibals are on the east side of a river. They have a boat which is big enough to carry at most two people. For both banks, if there are missionaries present on the bank, they cannot be outnumbered by cannibals, since the cannibals would eat the missionaries. The boat cannot cross the river by itself with no people on board. How can all missionaries and cannibals get to the other side alive?*

I've choosen to represent as state as a list containing five elements. The first element represents the number of missionaries on the east bank; the second represents the number of cannibals on the east bank; the third represents the number of missionaries on the west bank; the fourth represents the number of cannibals on the west bank; the fifth represents the location of the boat, which can either be east or west. Under this representation the initial state would be represented as (3 3 0 0 east).

**Are my operators correct? Or is there another way (using my representation of states) to define the problem operators?**

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

My problem operators are as follows:

```
    (defparameter *operators*
     '(boat-takes-missionary-east
     boat-takes-cannibal-east
     boat-takes-missionary-west
     boat-takes-cannibal-west
     boat-takes-missionary-missionary-east
     boat-takes-missionary-cannibal-east
     boat-takes-cannibal-cannibal-east
     boat-takes-missionary-missionary-west
     boat-takes-missionary-cannibal-west
     boat-takes-cannibal-cannibal-West)
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

Without getting into details, a simple way to approach this problem is a method called *generate-and-test*, where you generate all reachable states from an initial state and test for a solution (or reject undesired states).

Here is kind-of generic forward search function, accepting an initial-state, a next function that computes the list of next states (given a state and a current "path"), and applies a function to each visited state.

```
(defun forward-search (initial-state next function)
  (labels ((recurse (state path)
             (funcall function state path)
             (push state path)
             (dolist (state (funcall next state path))
               (recurse state path))))
    (recurse initial-state nil)))
```

For example, here is a search that starts from 0 and where possible neighbour states are, for each v below 5, either *v+1* or *v+2*:

```
(forward-search 0
                (lambda (v &optional p)
                  (declare (ignore p))
                  (if (< v 5)
                      (list (+ v 1) (+ v 2))
                      nil))
                (lambda (v path)
                  (declare (ignore v))
                  (print path)))
```

The trace is as follows, the path represents all intermediate states leading to current state (in reverse order):

```
NIL
(0)
(1 0)
(2 1 0)
(3 2 1 0)
(4 3 2 1 0)
(4 3 2 1 0)
(3 2 1 0)
(2 1 0)
(4 2 1 0)
(4 2 1 0)
(1 0)
(3 1 0)
(4 3 1 0)
(4 3 1 0)
(3 1 0)
(0)
(2 0)
(3 2 0)
(4 3 2 0)
(4 3 2 0)
(3 2 0)
(2 0)
(4 2 0)
(4 2 0)
```

You can use the path argument in your `next` function to reject states that already occur in your path (hint: you don't want to visit a state multiple times, as will likely occur in your case).

You need to have a way to represent a state and to compute the next states (see other answers).

Comment: I haven't come across generate-and-test method, in my brief study so far. I'll be sure to re-visit your comment in the future. Many thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

The operators you have chosen would need to be broken down anyway, so I'd rather use that representation directly.  Also, you don't need to tell whether the boat goes east or west, because it is already encoded in the states.  The only thing your operators would need to know is how many missionaries and how many cannibals are transported.

This means that you can represent the state transition with two numbers:

```
start state: (3 3 0 0 east)
transiton: (1 1)
end state: (2 2 1 1 west)
```

Comment: I didn't realise the location of the boat was encoded. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 1):

I would first of all abstract states: no-one needs to care about the representation of them.  The implementation of the state only needs three bits of information as you only need the numbers on one side and the side the boat is on.

Write a function which makes states, accepting arguments for both sides, and doing suitable sanity checks.  It is useful to use keyword arguments, because then you can use the supplied-p options to know whether you can default an argument from the other one or whether you need to sanity check it.

Write a function which checks states for legality: do the missionaries get eaten in a state? You can combine this with the previous function and end up with a function called something like `maybe-make-state` which will return a state, or `nil` if the missionaries would get eaten.

Write a predicate which tells you if a state is the desired outcome.

Write a function, using the above functions which, given a state, returns a list of all the legal child states.

Now, using these functions, you can write a search algorithm to search from a starting state.  This algorithm will need to be breadth-first (why?).